# Operator functions with character

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a new operator function with the , that will receive two Ints and return the SUM of this two ints, for that I try this command bellow:

```
func  (val: Int, val2: Int) -> Int{
    return val + val2
}

println(4543)//This line causes a error
```

But Xcode give me an error **"Expect a digit after integer literal prefix"**, How can I solve this problem? Is possible to create a operator with  and others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not declared  as an `operator`.

But unfortunately you won't be able to do that...

Comment: hum... How I can declare  as an operator, can you give me an example?

Comment: You won't be able to. This is not a legal operator character. But if you want to see an example, look in the Swift header at how `+` is declared. Or read my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#SECOperators

Comment: Thanks, I expected this!

Comment: If there were a sad kitty emoticon I'd be displaying it now!